# How Does Application Know CA's public Key in case of TLS/SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, x509certificate, public-key

In the case of SSL from a web browser to a web server the following things happen to my understanding.

1. Web browser downloads the web server's certificate, which contains the public key of the web server. This certificate is signed with the private key of a trusted certificate authority.
2. Web browser comes installed with the public keys of all of the major certificate authorities. It uses this public key to verify that the web server's certificate was indeed signed by the trusted certificate authority.

Now if instead of a web browser, my client is another application how it would have information on the public keys of all of the major certificate authorities

Comment: The answer is platform- and application-dependent. Many platforms also have a list of trusted CAs, and some browsers rely on the platform's list rather than providing their own. Please specify more details on your application's context so that a specific answer is possible.

Comment: suppose it's a java application that needs to consume an API from another application server via TLS . So what needs to be configured in the client java application so that it can validate the server's public certificate(signed by trusted CA's)

Comment: Java comes with its own set of trusted certificates. They are contained in a file in the distribution called `cacerts`. The Java TLS APIs use that file by default for checking certificate chains. And should that model for some reason prove inadequate, Java offers fairly robust customization options that can be accomplished in the code or by a simple command-line option to the launcher specifying an alternative file of trusted certificates.